# Asp.Net Web API content negotiation

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

…API/emailMessage/?emailId=test123

I have written the above URL using Web API to get the email in JSON data format(email body, sender, CC, To, etc).

Also, I have the requirement to allow download of email along with attachment for the same URL.

One way to do it is using content negotiation. I can use “MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream")” to send the content as downloadable.

Question is….
1. Which parameter in the GET request the user should request for JSON content or download of content? Or what is the correct way of asking the content type from HTTP client?
2. On the server side I can read what content type the user is asking and send the appropriate data just using case statement. Is there anything to be considered on the server side in this scenarios?

Thank you,
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Accept` request header is used to inform the server what media types the client supports.   However, do not be concerned about adding a format= parameter to your URI to request a different format.  It will not have a negative impact on your application.

Comment: There is big debate on URL format/design or Rest style or SEO URL. Which one makes more sense to use (Accept request header or Adding new parameter to the URL) ?

Comment: @EricSmith I am aware of most of the arguments. Using the Accept header can make caching more difficult because you are dependent on caches implementing Vary correctly.  The right choice depends on lots of factors.  But the "it's not RESTful" argument is a red herring.